# What type of graph is this? And can it be created using ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, graph

I have this chart that I'm attempting to replicate. It has two continuous variables for the X & Y axes, and charts the relationship between these two variables through time with a line.

[image]

My question has two parts:

- First, what is this type of chart called? It is unusual because the line between the points is determined by a third variable (the year) rather than their positions on the X axis.
- Second, does anyone know whether this can be achieved with ggplot? I have so far created a chart similar to the above but without the line connecting the points. This code
  `ggplot(data, aes(x = Weekly_Hours_Per_Person, y = GDP_Per_Hour)) + geom_point()` has gotten the below output:
  [image]
  But how to get the line over years?

Any help on either point will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `geom_path`, i.e.

```
libraray(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = Weekly_Hours_Per_Person, y = GDP_Per_Hour)) +
geom_point() + 
geom_path()
```

Answer (score 4):

Just expanding upon the original question. This is a path graph, and as explained [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_path.html):

> "geom_path() connects the observations in the order in which they appear in the data. geom_line() connects them in order of the variable on the x axis."

As an extension of your original question, you can label selected points where the line bends. Here is an example with reproducible data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(year = 1960:2006,
           Weekly_Hours_Per_Person = c(2:10, 9:0, 1:10, 9:1, 2:10),
           GDP_Per_Hour = 1:47 + rnorm(n = 47, mean = 0))

# Only label selected years
df_label <- filter(df, year %in% c(1960, 1968, 1978, 1988, 1997, 2006))
```

And use the `ggrepel` package to offset the labels from the vertices.

```
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(df, aes(Weekly_Hours_Per_Person, GDP_Per_Hour)) +
  geom_path() +
  geom_point(data = df_label) +
  geom_text_repel(data = df_label, aes(label = year)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-2, 12))
))
```

[image]